# Assign by value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, pass-by-value

I'd like to assign part of the DOM tree to global variable, so that there isn't reference with my variable and DOM tree any more. The part of the DOM tree should be copied to global variable and when I make changes to DOM tree it shouldn't change my variable.
Normal assignment does not do it.

clarification with code snippet:

```
var children;

var Test {

x: function(e) {
...
children = e.target.ownerDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].childNodes; // rowX
...
e.target.ownerDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = somethingElse; // rowY

}

}
```

The problem is that I want have something stored in `children` variable (rowX) and rowY will change `children` variable as a side effect, so there is some reference with the DOM tree yet.

thank you for tip

Comment: I'm sorry, but what? What's the question? How does the title relate to the body of the question you've written? Have you tried anything? What went wrong? What didn't work? Have you put any research into this at all? ...I'm not trying to be combative, but your question isn't clear to me, nor is there any suggestion of your putting any effort into solving this on your own. I'm ***not*** voting to close as yet, but may I suggest you read ['Writing the Perfect Question'](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints), and then edit/clarify the question you're asking?

Comment: @David Thomas I added clarification. If you're interested in this question just ask what isn't clear and I will make my question better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you may want to use the `cloneNode(deep:Boolean)` method:

```
var myVar = myNode.cloneNode(true);
```

Comment: Link to the [Mozilla Developer Center's entry for `cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.cloneNode).

Comment: +1 also important to note is that `childNodes` returns a live list.

Answer (score 1):

Where would this supposed "by value" part of the DOM be exactly?

One way you could try to accomplish something like this would be with jQuery:

```
var chunkByVal = $("#bigChunkOfDOM").html();
```

Comment: I don't think he's using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/KH8CA/

If your using jquery this is very easy.  Just grab your element and clone it.

```
var backupDom = $("#id").clone(true);
```

Comment: It's also super easy if you don't use jQuery ;)